# How to make an interactive link check like

Tags: javascript

According to Jinxuan Cang: I meant to extract something from a link: www.example.com?variable=value
I want to extract the variable `variable` How do I do that in jQuery/javaScript?

Comment: Do what, exactly?

Comment: Extract a variable for a URL, example: www.example.com?variable=value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you would like to extract q variable from the url. Use function getQueryVariable("*q*") to get *sometext*.

For example:

URL: example.com?var1=something&var2=100

getQueryVariable("var1") should be something,

getQueryVariable("var2") should be 100.

```
function getQueryVariable(variable)
    {
           var querystr = window.location.search.substring(1);
           var vars = querystr.split("&");
           for (var i=0; i < vars.length; i++) {
                   var pair = vars[i].split("=");
                   if(pair[0] == variable) return pair[1];
           }
           return false;
    }
```

Source cited: CSS-Tricks https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I wanted to know!